# Can the value of an item in a PHP associative array be created from values in the array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, php-7

I have a config.php as part of a web project which includes a multidimensional associative array.

```
$config = array(
    "db" => array(
        "server" => "localhost",
        "name" => "mydb",
        "user" => "user",
        "pwd" => "password"
    ),
    "urls" => array(
        "base_url" => "http://localhost/"
    ),
    # Omitted for brevity
);
```

Under the 'db' array I'd like to include a key called 'dsn' which would be a PDO DSN string defined within the array itself. The only way I've managed to do this is defining it separately:

```
$config['db']['dsn'] = 'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['server'] . ';dbname=' .  $config['db']['name'] . ';port=3306';
```

Is there anyway this could be defined in the array itself, like below?

```
...
"db" => array(
    "server" => "localhost",
    "name" => "mydb",
    "user" => "user",
    "pwd" => "password"
    "dsn" => #(some value here that uses "server" and "name")
),
...
```

Comment: Not sure if you can do that, but you might also specify them separately `$server = "localhost";
$name = "mydb";` and use them creating the array.

Comment: Didn't think about doing it that way... that's a decent workaround. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use previous keys before declaring the entire array. Just have a helper function and put your code inside it to return the DSN.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, and it's a bit cleaner too.

Answer (score 0):

If You want the array `dsn` to update  when u make change to `$config`, then you can use class with [magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) or the  [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.